# ActiveRecord::Base with SimpleDelegator throws Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I remove the warning `warning: delegator does not forward private method #to_ary`?

Following is a code snippet for recreating the problem with the given technologies:

- Ruby 3.2.1
- Rails 7.0.4.3

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    "foobar"
  end
end

class FooDelegator < SimpleDelegator
  def name
    "name"
  end
end

pry(main)> [FooDelegator.new(Foo.new)].flatten
(pry):12: warning: delegator does not forward private method #to_ary
=> [#<Foo:0x00007f3fa3b1ebf0 id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

**EDIT**:
This issue was also posted on Github because I figured that it actually belongs to ActiveRecord (rails).

**Link**: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `public :to_ary` in the ActiveRecord class to convert the private method to public:

```rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    "foobar"
  end

  public :to_ary
end

class FooDelegator < SimpleDelegator
  def name
    "name"
  end
end
```

Comment: Even though this works fine, would you be so kind to elaborate why `to_ary` could be private in ActiveRecord itself?

Comment: It's been [private since at least Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L388-L435) so I guess I would ask why you expect it not to be.

Comment: Doesn't it seem strange to you not being able to use these two thing seemlessly together?

Comment: No, why would it?